# Customize Tiles in Windows 10?(Size, Color, Icon)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to customize the Tiles in the Windows 10 Start menu. Personally, I would like to have no Background color and make the icons bigger just as you can see in the image below.

[image]

I already researched for a couple hours on Google, but I couldn't find anything useful. I already tried the Software "[Oblytile](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865)" but it does not work with Windows 10. I do know that there is an App called "TileCreator", but in order for it to work you also have to download another app called "Tile Creator Proxy" and you have to create an account which I am not willing to do.

There must be a much better way. Are there any known Registry hacks or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a little tool that can customize the tiles the way you like it, the tool name is **Win10Tile** and it can do the job,
You can download it from Xda developers forum
http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10/development/win10tile-native-custom-windows-10-t3248677

And here is an article that explain how it works
http://www.intowindows.com/win10tile-create-custom-start-menu-tiles-in-windows-10/

ps: this program supports only Windows 10 with November Update (Threshold 2)

Comment: Thank you very much. The Program sadly only lets me change the Size and a color. That is 75% :) The Problem is now that i cant make it transparent. But as i told you, the other stuff works just fine, so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

To make it appear somewhat transparent, try changing the color to the one of the start screen already (same shade of grey). Then it will at least look transparent, even though it isn't :)